# Google Translate Android listener

Tags: android, service, clipboardmanager

I came upon Google Translate on Android, and see that it seems to have Clipboard listener that runs forever(whenever something is copied, the app pops up). I have tried to replicate this on my project by putting clipboardListener on a Service which restart itself in onDestroy(), but it does not work out. Does anyone knows how can i replicate this?